# Validation in table with dynamic rows in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a table with dynamic rows, when I press "add row" main row is copied and added to array. But when it copied - id copied too, and I don't need to change this ID. 
I copy main field like this:

```
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    var copy = angular.copy($scope.item[0]);
    $scope.item.push(copy)
  }
```

validate is working like this :

```
ng-class='{"is-invalid": tableForm[field.id].$invalid}'
```

I was thinking to add second `ng-form` for `<tr>`, with dynamic name like : `ng-form="{{row + $index}}"`, but in webstorm it highlight like error, so I guess it must be static name.. Now when I have invalid field - all column will be red (error). How can I without change ID's validate fields separately?
[My plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKXBXArCmoxVnmS6ubbB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

use $index in name field

change html file in your plunker as below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='App'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <h1>table</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat='item in item[0].field'>{{item.name}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody ng-form='tableForm'>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in item'>
          <td>{{$index}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat='field in row.field'>
            <input type="text"
                   ng-model='field.value' 
                   name='{{$index}}'
                   required
                   ng-class='{"is-invalid": tableForm[$parent+$index].$invalid}'>
          </td>
          <td ng-if='$index !== 0'
              style='color:red;cursor:pointer'
              ng-click='removeRow($index)'>X</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click='addRow()'>add row</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately it not works, couse added fields is copied from original, so every row will be include 0, 1, 2, 3. and error will be the same

Comment: not working, and unfortunately I don't need to add new field on my table, but thx anyway)

Comment: What is the actual condition? @YoroDiallo
validation right!!  explain more

Comment: in some way yes, validation is needed but fields with numbers not(